# Inconsistent behaviour when accessing setters between TS and using TS in JS

Tags: typescript

So my use case is simple, I have a custom element and trying to simplify the binding management on the elements attributes.

Here is a very simple use case, the goal is to have more attributes later on so trying to make `attributeChangedCallback` ready for that.

```js
export class Input extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['label']
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} text
   */
  set label(text) {
    const span = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('span')
    if (span) span.textContent = text
  }

  /**
   * @param {'label'} name
   * @param {string | null} _oldValue
   * @param {string | null} newValue
   */
  attributeChangedCallback(name, _oldValue, newValue) {
    this[name] = newValue || '' // Duplicate property 'label' ts(2718)

  }
}
```

The error that I'm having on TypeScript v4.5.4 is the following:

[image: error message of the problem: Duplicate property 'label']

> (parameter): name: "label"
>
> @param name
>
> Duplicate property 'label' ts(2718)

...showing `this[name]` as the code with the error.

I tried really quickly to do this in TypeScript Playground (REPL) and there were no error there. I also then tried to make a new repo quickly to test it with a local setup of a TypeScript file and still no error. So I tried also quickly to add a JavaScript file and got the error again (In case there were something with my `tsconfig.json`). So it like TypeScript in `.ts` files behaves differently from TypeScript in `.js`.

In case you are curious, here is a link to my repo that reproduces this. https://github.com/DennisSkoko/typescript-problem

Comment: (I've done it for you this time.)

Comment: That's really odd. Also odd is if I change `foo.js` to `foo.ts`, I get errors indicating that TypeScript isn't using the JSDoc type annotations. I thought it did without extra config (and can't find a config option for it).

Comment: Is there any reason you are compiling even the `*.js` files along side `*.ts` files? Is there a possibility to change that ??

Comment: @NalinRanjan This repo is just to showcase that the problem only exists in JS files and not in TS files. My actual setup is only JS files, no TS files. I have it like that for backend in order to not having to build. I figured I will also give it a try TS in JS in my frontend project as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry for the image, will avoid it in the future. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

In the `foo.js` if I have this(please mind the parameter's description of `attributeChangedCallback`)...

```
export class Input extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['label']
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} text
   */
  set label(text) {
    const span = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('span')
    if (span) span.textContent = text
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} name
   * @param {string | null} _oldValue
   * @param {string | null} newValue
   */
  attributeChangedCallback(name, _oldValue, newValue) {
    this[name] = newValue || ''
  }
}
```

I start getting following error on compilation...

```
> tsc

src/foo.js:20:5 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Input'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Input'.

20     this[name] = newValue || ''
       ~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ lint: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
....
....
```

And that's `tsc` at play compiling even the `*.js` files and enforcing typing restriction(s).

Then I change `foo.js` to following and then `npm run lint` finishes without any error...

```
export class Input extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['label']
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} text
   */
  set label(text) {
    const span = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('span')
    if (span) span.textContent = text
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} name
   * @param {string | null} _oldValue
   * @param {string | null} newValue
   */
  attributeChangedCallback(name, _oldValue, newValue) {
    this.label = newValue || ''
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that when changing from `this[name]` to `this.label` removes the error. Which I'm doing for now as a workaround until I figure out the actual problem. My only problem with this solution is that the code is not really maintainable, this example was very simple but most of my component has at least 3-5 attributes.

Comment: As for why you are getting a different error, how did you test the file? Did you just copy my example from Stack Overflow or did you clone the repo? The code example from the repo but thinking if you are maybe using a different tsconfig setup which results in a different error message?

Comment: I used the repo only... The problem is `tsc` is also compiling the `*.js` files applying settings from `tsconfig.json`. If we omit inclusion of `*.js` source files from compilation, even in that case we will not see the error. Only when compiling `*.js` files using `tsc` is causing this.

Comment: If you are having only `*.js` files and not compile through `tsc`, then `this[name]` should work. It's the typing restriction of `tsc` is what is causing `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Input'`. But this shouldn't happen with only javascript all around.

Comment: If I take the repo and do as has been stated in the question, I too get the same error as stated in the OP. The different error is after I made a change in the source(js file). And the change is, in the parameter description of `attributeChangedCallback`, I changed `@param {'label'} name` to `@param {string} name`, and after that I started seeing the error which I have mentioned...

Comment: @DennisSkoko - This sounds like something to raise on the TypeScript issue list. It looks a lot like a possible bug, and you have a fairly clean replication for it.

Comment: @NalinRanjan Ahh, I see now. Sorry, must have been a little confused when I read your post. Totally missed your change on the type for `name`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I'm thinking the same. I figured I try here first as a sanity check so I'm not doing anything. I usually blame myself before the library. :D

I will try and create an issue on their repo, will update this post based on the info I get from the issue. Thanks both of you for your time on this.